# desaparece mi texto

Tags: html, css

tengo un button y al pasar el mouse el texto no desaparece, al igual que tengo un a href pero al pasarle el mouse se muestra la animacion pero el texto desaparece, adjunto codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven en donde esta el div button al pasar el mouse se aplica la animacion y se sigue viendo el texto pero al pasarlo por el div con el a href desaparece, si hay otra forma que un boton me redireccione a una seccion de la misma pagina me vendria mejor, gracias!!!

---

dejando eso ocupo ayuda para centrar dos botones,

```
introducir el código aquí

section a{
display: inline-block;
padding: 7px 0;
color: #283773;
text-decoration: none;
width: 110px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 50px;
background: #fff ;}


@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
section{
    flex-direction: column;
}

section > img{
    height: 40%;
}

.contenedor-texto{
    text-align: center;
}}

  @media screen and (max-width:600px){
section{
    flex-direction: column;
}

section > img{
    height: 25%;
}}
```

aca el html de una seccion el cual deberia llevar dos botones, uno que regrese a la seccion anterior y otro que lleve a la siguiente seccion.

```
`introducir el código aquí`<section id="sec1" >
    <div class="contenedor-texto">
        <h2>Acerca de</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, possimus.
        </p>
        <a href="#sec2">Objetivo</a>
    </div>
    <img src="../freelancer_inicio/img/si.jpg" alt="" >
</section>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: a lo que me refiero es por que desaparece eltexto cuando paso el cursor sobre el boton creado con a href

Comment: Es difícil que se te pueda ayudar. No estas agregando tu código correctamente. Te falta el código CSS y HTML correctamente. No muestres tantas imágenes sino, el código. Edita tu pregunta y agrega solamente códigos usando el icono **{ }** de este editor.

Comment: Todo puede estar en el button:hover y en tu class="botón cuatro". Pero para que se te pueda ayudar, se tiene que revisar el código.